# Uploading multiple files to WordPress with AJAX and FormData

Tags: wordpress

I'm running WordPress 4.5.4. I'm uploading files with AJAX and FormData onto WordPress. How can I upload multiple files in a single AJAX request?

Here's my code:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<input type="file" name="file2" id="file2">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="Upload" onclick="upload();return false;">

<script type="text/javascript">
function upload(){
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("action", "upload-attachment");

  var fileInputElement = document.getElementById("file");
  formData.append("async-upload", fileInputElement.files[0]);
  formData.append("name", fileInputElement.files[0].name);

  <?php $my_nonce = wp_create_nonce('media-form'); ?>
  formData.append("_wpnonce", "<?php echo $my_nonce; ?>");
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  }
  xhr.open("POST","/wp-admin/async-upload.php",true);
  xhr.send(formData);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm just doing the same thing. Can you please answer when you will find a solution?

Comment: Sai Kiran Sripada - did you find a solution of this problem?

Comment: @MarekZygmunt Sorry for the late response! I didn't find a way to upload multiple files simultaneously but I achieved it by sending another ajax request in the callback function.

Comment: Are you able to deliver your code here or article that helped you?

Comment: @MarekZygmunt Yup! Delivered it, but still looking for a workaround to this issue.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239665/form-data-upload-multiple-files-through-ajax-together-with-text-fields