# form data upload multiple files through ajax together with text fields

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

Good day all,

I have a form wil multiple fields in it. Also, the form is being submitted through form data method using ajax to a php file.

The following is the javascript code submitting the form data.

```
$(".update").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
        url: 'post_reply.php',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType:false,
        processData: false,
        data: function(){
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('image',$('#picture').get(0).files[0]);
            data.append('body' , $('#body').val());
            data.append('uid', $('#uid').val());
            return data;
        }(),
            success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
            },
        error: function(xhr, result, errorThrown){
            alert('Request failed.');
        }
        });
        $('#picture').val('');
$('#body').val('');
});
```

And, the following is the actual form:

```
<textarea name=body id=body class=texarea placeholder='type your message here'></textarea>
<input type=file name=image id=picture >
<input name=update value=Send type=submit class=update id=update  />
```

This form and javascript work good as they are. However, I am trying to be able to upload multiple files to the php file using this one single type=file field attribute. As it is now, it can only take one file at a time. How do I adjust  both the form and the javascript code to be able to handle multiple files uploads?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is ajax, html and php global you can access. Let me know if it works for you.

```
// Updated part
jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});

// Full Ajax request
$(".update").click(function(e) {
    // Stops the form from reloading
    e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        url: 'post_reply.php',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType:false,
        processData: false,
        data: function(){
            var data = new FormData();
            jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                data.append('file-'+i, file);
            });
            data.append('body' , $('#body').val());
            data.append('uid', $('#uid').val());
            return data;
        }(),
            success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
            },
        error: function(xhr, result, errorThrown){
            alert('Request failed.');
        }
        });
        $('#picture').val('');
$('#body').val('');
});
```

Updated HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input id="file" name="file[]" type="file"  multiple/>
  <input class="update" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Now, in PHP, you should be able to access your files:

```
// i.e.    
$_FILES['file-0']
```

Comment: Actually, it seems to work but with one slight problem. When i choose files from the computer, and then press the submit button...the alert function works yes but still, the browser seems to reload..or displays the loading icon spinning. I want that when the submit button is clicked, that the file is sent to the php file and bring up the alert box. That when i press the browser's refresh button, that it does not ask me if I want to resubmit information. Currently, the browser ask me if i want to resubmit.....how to fix? ..when button is clicked, i dont want browser loading at all.

Comment: I've updated my answer, should be ok now. You need to add event param to your function like so: `function(e)` and use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent form from reloading. See updated answer.

Comment: @loelsonk I followed your link to save multiple files browed. I chose more than 1 file from my system and alerted a text inside function below: jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                data.append('file-'+i, file);
            });
But it alerted only one time. I am able to save the last browsed file only. How can I able to save all the browsed file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.

Assuming your HTML is like this:

```
<form id="theform">
    <textarea name="body" id="body" class="texarea" placeholder="type your message here"></textarea>
    <!-- note the use of [] and multiple -->
    <input type="file" name="image[]" id="picture" multiple>
    <input name="update" value="Send" type="submit" class="update" id="update">
</form>
```

You could simply do

```
$("#theform").submit(function(e){
    // prevent the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'post_reply.php',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType:false,
        processData: false,
        // pass the form in the FormData constructor to send all the data inside the form
        data: new FormData(this),
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, result, errorThrown){
            alert('Request failed.');
        }
    });
    $('#picture').val('');
    $('#body').val('');
});
```

Because we used `[]`, you would be accessing the files as an array in the PHP.

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES['image']); // should be an array i.e. $_FILES['image'][0] is 1st image, $_FILES['image'][1] is the 2nd, etc
?>
```

More information:

- [FormData constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)
- [Multiple file input](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/multiple-file-input/)

Comment: i tested codes. I have a php file that detects when a file or files are being submitted. Here is the issue:  when i select 0 files, the php file says that it got a file. When i select 1 file, it says it received a file. And when i select two files, after clicking the submit button, the page just refreshes and form data is cleared. What is the issue?

Comment: It's because the button is a `type="submit"` button within a form -- meaning, by default, if you click on the button it will submit the form and reload the page. You want to prevent that. Check my edit, particularly the HTML and JS code. Notice that I am attaching an `onsubmit` event handler to the form opposed to `onclick` event handler to the button.